# App.Config change value

Tags: c#, app-config

This is my App.Config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="lang" value="English"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

With this code I make the change

```
lang = "Russian";
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("lang", lang);
}
```

But it not change. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write values in app.config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758598/write-values-in-app-config-file)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You cannot use AppSettings static object for this. Try this

```
string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);          
string configFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "App.config");
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();         
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFile;          
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["YourThing"].Value = "New Value"; 
config.Save();
```

Comment: But it restarts... I making the change on Form closing... When I run program again nothing change

Comment: do you get any exceptions? Are you using WinForms?

Comment: On my .Net (4.5) with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, I can have System.Configuration but no such object as System.Configuration.Configuration.

Comment: It throws NullReferenceException when setting the value. config.AppSettings.Settings count is zero though I have a key in my appSettings. I am on c# 4.5

Comment: @TechJerk Are you using app.config or web.config?

Answer (score 99):

`AppSettings.Set` does not persist the changes to your configuration file.  It just changes it in memory.  If you put a breakpoint on `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("lang", lang);`, and add a watch for `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[0]` you will see it change from "English" to "Russian" when that line of code runs.

The following code (used in a console application) will persist the change.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdateSetting("lang", "Russian");
    }

    private static void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
    {
        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
        configuration.Save();

        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
}
```

**From this post:** http://vbcity.com/forums/t/152772.aspx

> One major point to note with the above is that if you are running this from the debugger (within Visual Studio) then the app.config file will be overwritten each time you build. The best way to test this is to build your application and then navigate to the output directory and launch your executable from there. Within the output directory you will also find a file named YourApplicationName.exe.config which is your configuration file. Open this in Notepad to see that the changes have in fact been saved.

Comment: How I can make the change then?

Comment: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[0] will not do nothing alone... Please fill the code

Comment: So I must write System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[0] = lang? Because that give me error

Comment: I copied your code and run on VS 2012 c# 4.5 , it isn't working. I did check the bin/debug folder config file. It works only when I add the "configFileMap" as given in accepted answer

Comment: It doesn't save permanently. When I debug I can see the value is changed but after complete execution, previous value is restored.

Comment: For more robust code you could add a test if the key already exists:
`if (configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key] == null)
  configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
else
  configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;`

Comment: Nice Major Point.

Answer (score 13):

when use "**ConfigurationUserLevel.None**" your code is right run when you click in nameyourapp.exe in debug folder. .
but when your do developing app on visual stdio not right run!! because "vshost.exe" is run.

following parameter solve this problem :
"**Application.ExecutablePath**"

***try this : (Tested in VS 2012 Express For Desktop)***

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
config.AppSettings.Settings["PortName"].Value = "com3";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

**my english not good , i am sorry.**

Answer (score 7):

That worked for me in WPF application:

```
string configPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "YourApplication.exe");
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configPath);
config.AppSettings.Settings["currentLanguage"].Value = "En";
config.Save();
```

Comment: @jned29 feel free to upvote my answer, if it helps to you:).

Answer (score 3):

```
    private static string GetSetting(string key)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
    }

    private static void SetSetting(string key, string value)
    {
        Configuration configuration =
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
        configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
```

Comment: You may not want to save the config in ConfigurationSaveMode.Full. This will ad a ton of stuff to your app.config that you do not want. The rest is good.

Comment: You may also want to combine with the `Application.ExecutablePath` option for calling `OpenExeConfiguration`, as mentioned in @Amin Ghaderi's answer

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by fenix2222 (which worked for me) I had to modify the last line to:

```
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Without this, the new value was still being written to the config file but the old value was retrieved when debugging.

Answer (score 2):

For a .NET 4.0 console application, none of these worked for me.  So I modified Kevn Aenmey's answer as below and it worked:

```
private static void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
{
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.
        OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
    configuration.Save();

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Only the first line is different, constructed upon the actual executing assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Jahmic for the answer.
Worked properly for me.

another useful code snippet that read the values and return a string:

```
public static string ReadSetting(string key)
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection appSettings = (System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection)cfg.GetSection("appSettings");
        return appSettings.Settings[key].Value;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To update entries other than `appsettings`, simply use `XmlDocument`.

```
public static void UpdateAppConfig(string tagName, string attributeName, string value)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
    var tags = doc.GetElementsByTagName(tagName);
    foreach (XmlNode item in tags)
    {
        var attribute = item.Attributes[attributeName];
        if (!ReferenceEquals(null, attribute))
            attribute.Value = value;
    }
    doc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
Utility.UpdateAppConfig("endpoint", "address", "http://localhost:19092/NotificationSvc/Notification.svc");

Utility.UpdateAppConfig("network", "host", "abc.com.au");
```

This method can be improved to cater for appSettings values as well.