# Spring.NET PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer using ${my value}

Tags: configuration, spring.net

My Spring.NET configuration is using the following type syntax and is working ok.

```
<object id="JohnUsingVariableSource"
    type="XmlConfig.StringInjection.Person, XmlConfig">
  <property name="Name" value="${JohnsFullName}" />
</object>
```

Values for the ${JohnsFullName} placeholder are configured in the app.config file. My requirements have changed and I know need to get the name from the database at startup. How is it possible to overwrite the value in the app.config file ? Can I do it in code without opening the app.config (as here [App.Config change value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149556/c-sharp-app-config-change-value)), does spring.NET have a way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that without modifying the app.config file. Simply implement a custom [`IVariableSource`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-variablesource):

```
public interface IVariableSource
{
  string ResolveVariable(string name);
}
```

In the `ResolveVariable` method you read from the db.

The first variable source configured in your config will be the one used by the spring config, if I recall correctly.