# Changing Connection string and save it for Entity Framework at deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, app-config

I have a desktop app that I am nearing finishing proof of concept on but I have a final function I want to add but I do not think it is possible

The app which will finally be deployed uses Entity Framework and is written in VS 2010. The app needs to be deployed in two different companies which have the same SQL database structure (but different names `Database1` or `Database2`) but they are hosted on different servers (eg `Server1` and `Server2`)

It would be neat to be able to set `Server1` or `Server2` and `Database1` or `Database2` in a wpf form and "save" the application setting rather than have to deploy twice with different EF models.

This means writing over the `app.config` file at run time and from reading around this seem difficult see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149556/app-config-change-value) but this refers to general settings not the configuration string or am I missing the point

In my case should my `app.config` is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OsmiContext" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/OsmiModel.csdl|res://*/OsmiModel.ssdl|res://*/OsmiModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=**Server1**\**DATABASE1**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<STANDARDUSER>;Password=<STANDARDPASSWORD>Qu3r3y3;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So I think my code should look something like this I think (the `String NewConnection` would in fact be built in the method at run time) Am I right or missing something?

```
<build so new App.Config Method>
String NewConnection =@"metadata=res://*/OsmiModel.csdl|res://*/OsmiModel.ssdl|res://*/OsmiModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=**Server2**\**DATABASE2**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<STANDARDUSER>;Password=<STANDARDPASSWORD>Qu3r3y3;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

string appPath    =System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);          
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
config.AppSettings.Settings["OsmiContext"].Value = NewConnection ;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Comment: does the app for the same companies share the same functionality? if so then add 2 different connection strings..  and a variable that can differentiate between the 2 companies there are several ways to approach this without making it so difficult

Comment: Why don't you just have two `app.config` - `app.company1.config` and `app.company2.config` and just pick the correct one at the time of installation and copy that to the customer's server

Comment: 2 different app.configs would be best, overwriting data doesn't seem right. Exposing password from one company to another company alone should be reason enough not to do this...

Comment: @MethodMan yes they share the same functionality as they are the same group of companies and the app links to the Group ERP SQL database. The problem with your approach is how do I tell the Entity Model which of the two connection strings to use or do I create a conditional dbContext base on my variable

Comment: @AlexanderDerck  Yes I can have two app.config but I wanted to give the users the ability to pick as they all work for the same Group of companies and there are times when a user in CompanyA will do the same job in CompanyB due to illness etc

Comment: @marc_s see the above comments, but yes I could have two app.config

Comment: How are you deploying? If using msdeploy, look into parameters.xml.