# Set Config value

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder to access my json configuration file. While the get works fine I wonder is it possible to use it to modify file values?

Comment: [documentation says No](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder)

Comment: at the end, did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. 
 What you want is against the configuration principles. The purpose of configuration is to one-way-control the application without the need to modify the code. 
 If you want to modify a value in configuration then this is not a "configuration value". You should have such values stored in a different way e.g. as user personalization settings, or something similar (depends on your case)

Comment: But the possibility of modifying the config exist with the classic xml config http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149556/app-config-change-value I think that it is not supported with json config