# set TextBox text from App.config in WPF, XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I set my TextBox text as the value in the App.config file

my App.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Hours" value="12"/>
    <add key="Minutes" value="00"/>
  </appSettings>
```

How can set the value of `Minutes` as the TextBox text and make it update whenever the value of `Minutes` update

```
<TextBox x:Name="Minutes_Top" Text="00"/>
```

I tried adding this Line in the top:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:_10KHours.Properties"
```

And add this line in the TextBox

```
Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Mode=OneWay}"
```

But it didn't work, the text is "*_10KHours.Properties.Settings*"

I want that the text In Minutes_Top will be 00 like the value in the `App.config` and change when the value change (when The value in the App.config change or the text change so the App.config value will be change)

Comment: There is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149556/app-config-change-value][1]

Comment: @faikyldrm thank you, but it's not helping me, I need this in xaml not c#

Comment: You haven't specified a Binding Path.

Comment: @Clemens It's not duplicate because the answer there didn't helped me

Comment: Let me repeat myself, you haven't specified a Binding Path. `Settings.Default` is the settings object. It has properties that you can bind to.

Comment: @Clemens Thank  You, So what should I do?

Comment: Bind to one of the properties, of course! By specifying a Path, e.g. Path=Minutes.

Comment: @Clemens This isn't working - `Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Minutes, Mode=OneWay}"`

Comment: You have created the application settings in a wrong way. Use Properties->Settings in your Visual Studio project.