# Modify appSettings section of web.config file programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a user page which has a textbox & a button. Now there is an `AppSetting` section in `web.config` file in which I am storing a key value. From the aspx page, I want to update the value for this key to whatever value we enter in the textbox.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myStoreID" value="0000"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: You want this value to be changed while application is running? And it will be changed more than once by different users?

Comment: This has been answered several times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149556/app-config-change-value

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I want Key value will be changed once by only one user this will be admin user who will input value & whatever value he puts it will be change in web.config file

Comment: Did you try to follow the answers suggested in other comments?