# c# app.config file changes and i get pop up to say yes

Tags: c#, app-config

I am setting values in app.config using this code

```
string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);          
string configFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "App.config");
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();         
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFile;          
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["YourThing"].Value = "New Value"; 
config.Save();
```

I works fine, but when the data in app.config changes it asks me (pop up) for changes in app.config. I dont want it to ask for pop up for saving.

How can i stop from getting popup and also save app.config in background.

Thanks

Comment: UAC popup? Are these user settings you want to save? If so you should use user level settings instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357453/512365

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the `AppSetting` section after saving it like

```
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```