# The connection string property has not been initialized C# and XML

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I'm trying to test the connection and save the credentials in config file but I keep getting this error " The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"

Here's the C# code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("server=");
            str.Append(textBox1.Text);
            str.Append(";database=");
            str.Append(textBox2.Text);
            str.Append(";UID=");
            str.Append(textBox3.Text);
            str.Append(";password=");
            str.Append(textBox4.Text);
            string strcon = str.ToString();
            updateConfigFile(strcon);

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

            //Refresh Connection String each time else
            //it will use previous connection string.
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

            //Check the new connection string is working or not
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from egtab3");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected Sucessfully");
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void updateConfigFile(string con)
    {
        //Updating Config File
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

        //Loading the Config File
        xmldoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        foreach (XmlElement xElement in xmldoc.DocumentElement)
        {
            if (xElement.Name == "connectionStrings")
            {
                //Setting the connection string
                xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[4].Value = con;
            }
        }
        //writing the connection string in config file
        xmldoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
    }
```

and here's the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="con" providerName="using System.Data.SqlClient" 
connectionString=""/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In you app.config the connectionstring value is empty, in your code the connectionstring build manually is never used to call the updateConfigFile method (and by the way I don't know if UID is a valid key for Sql Server) So what else do you expect to happen when you try to open the connection?

Comment: Thank you . I updated the code. Now i get this error "the index being passed is out of range". what do i do now?

Comment: Count the attributes expected in a connectionstring entry. There are three attributes so the correct range for index is 0 to 2 with 2 the one you should use not 4

Comment: Thank you!. That worked. It says connected successfully. Now the thing is the details are not being saved in config file. What do i do now?

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: If its about connection, I tried with invalid credentials. It says login failed. Connection is working fine. I checked the app.config file. There is nothing stored in it.

Comment: You code doesn't write the app.config but the config file present in the run directory of your program. This file is named after your executable name with the config extension. You will find it in the subfolder BIN\DEBUG (or x86 variant) under your project folder

Comment: got it. you're right. It was named same as the exe file. anyways I tried opening it and xml code showed up with no changes. It was empty as before. I tried fiddling around and it throws "Object reference is not set to the instance of an object" exception.

Comment: Check ....vshost.exe.config

Comment: Done that. No change

Comment: Remember that every time you start a new debug session the file app.config is copied back in the BIN\DEBUG folder so the content is reset every time you press F5 to run the app inside vs. What happens if you launch the application standalone?

Comment: Thank you! That did it. the contents are saving in the file when i run it standalone. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad to be of help. See you again on SO

Comment: Firstly, use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Secondly, without admin permissions, your application will not be able to write to the Program Files folder, where your application will be installed at the end user. In any case you must not overwrite the file `app.config`. Save these settings in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

Add update before getting from config

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("server=");
                str.Append(textBox1.Text);
                str.Append(";database=");
                str.Append(textBox2.Text);
                str.Append(";UID=");
                str.Append(textBox3.Text);
                str.Append(";password=");
                str.Append(textBox4.Text);

                updateConfigFile(str);

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

                //Refresh Connection String each time else
                //it will use previous connection string.
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

                //Check the new connection string is working or not
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from egtab3");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Connected Sucessfully");
                con.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you . I updated the code. Now i get this error "the index being passed is out of range". what do i do now?

Comment: I think problem is here xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[4].Value = con; 

Why did you set to 4? Change index to 2

Comment: Thank you!. That worked. It says connected successfully. Now the thing is the details are not being saved in config file. What do i do now?

Comment: To update config I would recommend follow this thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149556/app-config-change-value
also 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357240/change-the-value-in-app-config-file-dynamically